# How to solve a method of characteristics problem with only a point boundary condition?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am familiar with the method of characteristics. However, I have a problem that appears to only have a specified solution at a single point:

Solving for $V(x,y)$, where

$V_xy-V_y(ax+bx^2y) = -cx^2y^2-dx^2-ey^2$, $\quad V(0,0) = 0$.

and where (a,b,c,d,e) are scalar constants.

I'm not sure how to define my "data" and propagate it to execute the method. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The solution is only uniquely defined along the characteristic through $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary reduced to one point doesn't define a unique solution.

For example in order to illustrate with a simplified example :

For example in the case of $a=d=e=0$
$$yV_x-bx^2yV_y=-cx^2y^2$$

$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-bx^2y}=\frac{dV}{-cx^2y^2}$

First characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-bx^2y}\quad\implies\quad 3y-bx^3=c_1$

Second characteristic equation from $\frac{dy}{-bx^2y}=\frac{dV}{-cx^2y^2}\quad\implies\quad V-\frac{c}{2b}y^2=c_2$

General solution of the PDE from $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$V(x,y)=\frac{c}{2b}y^2+F(3y-bx^3)$$
$F$ is an arfitrary function ( to be determined according to the condition ).

CONDITION : $V(0,0)=0=\frac{c}{2b}0^2+F(3*0-b*0^3)=F(0)$

This implies $F(0)=0$.

They are imfinity many functions $F$ such as $F(0)=0$. Thus they are infinity many solutions $V(x,y)=\frac{c}{2b}y^2+F(3y-bx^3)$ .

Comment: I really appreciate that, thank you